# What does "being a Cavalier" mean?

Tags: dnd-4e, paragon-path

A player in my campaign started as a Cavalier (from Heroes of the Forgotten Kingdoms) but in his latest gained level, he got a power from the Paladin (from Player's Handbook).

> **Prerequisite:** Only a cavalier can take [the Valiant Cavalier] paragon path.

- When he hits level 11, will he be able to get the **Valiant Cavalier** paragon path?
- What does being a Cavalier mean?
- Does he need to gain all his powers gained from the cavalier?
- Does he only need to have started as a cavalier?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Cavalier is the Class of the character. There are class-based powers, but it is possible to gain powers that belong to other classes (for example by multiclassing, or using the Half-Elf Dilettante racial trait).

In this case, a lot of the classes from the Heroes of X books are considered subtypes of previous classes. A Cavalier is actually a subtype of Paladin, so they're eligible for any Paladin powers (on the rare levels when they're allowed to pick a power), feats, and paragon paths, as long as they don't require specific Paladin features they don't have.
(This paragraph was taken from [Oblivious Sage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/3548/oblivious-sage)'s comments)

So while your player has a power taken from the Paladin class, he is still a Cavalier and thus allowed to choose the Valiant Cavalier paragon path.

Answer (score 0):

As ioanwigmore said, if you start as a cavalier you will always be a cavalier with the same character (regardless of multiclasses). Likewise since cavalier is a build or sub-class of Paladin the player has access to paladin powers, feats, and paragon paths as well in addition to those geared specifically to cavaliers.